# Prevent SSIS for creating an empty csv file at destination

Tags: ssis-2012

I created a SSIS to export to a csv file 
I don't wan't my SSIS to create an empty file if there is no data.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks,

Comment: Oh man I read this question wrong at first, haha.

Comment: whats wrong on this

Comment: Nothing, just skimming I saw the name of a terrorist group.

Answer (score 0):

Are you suggesting that when your project will create the CSV if there are no rows?

If that is the case - keep a row count.

If row count = 0 at the end the delete the file.

Comment: Yes that is the case.. But at what step i need to delete file and how.

Comment: When would you expect to delete the file? Surely at the stage where no rows could be written to it? Use the **File System Task**

Comment: But i want to delete only empty files right. How i can mention condition at File System Task.